# Simplifying equation with fraction powers

Tags: approximation, binomial-theorem

I am unable to see how the following equation simplifies (approximately). Is a binomial approximation used, and if so how?

In the question we are told $\frac{1}{A} \ll 1$

$A^{2/3} -(A-4)^{2/3}\approx \frac{8}{3}\frac{1}{A^{1/3}}$

Comment: Instead of $A$, I'll take $x$ so as to not confuse with matrices, etc. Take the expression
$$
x^{2/3} - (x-4)^{2/3}
$$
Divide by $x^{2/3}$ to get
$$
\frac{x^{2/3} - (x-4)^{2/3}}{ x^{2/3}} = 1- (1-\frac{4}{x})^{2/3}
$$
Now we use the approximation
$$
(1+y)^{\alpha} \approx 1+\alpha y
$$
if $y$ is small ...

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much!